# How to get Package ID in windows phone 8.0 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone silverlight app 8.1 that uses:

```
var Version = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.Version;
```

Which successfully returns the package version. Unfortunately when I duplicate this code for windows phone silverlight 8.0 I get a "Not implemented exception".

I noticed that this information is stored in package manifest, and I have also noticed that there is no package manifest in my unit test application for 8.0. Im not sure if it correlates or how to fix it, but it doesn't seem right to me that the libraries would be there to get that information but then not be implimented for SL80.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code get Version from your `Package.appxmanifest`

```
Version version = new Version(Package.Current.Id.Version.Major,
                                            Package.Current.Id.Version.Minor,
                                            Package.Current.Id.Version.Build,
                                            Package.Current.Id.Version.Revision);

string packege = version.Build.ToString();
```

And if you want Version from `AssemblyInfo.cs` then code as per below :

```
string package = "";
var versionAttribute = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), true).GetValue(0) as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute;

if (versionAttribute != null)
{
   package = versionAttribute.Version.Tostring();
}
```